# Blazor radio buttons in one component unselecting radio buttons from the others

Tags: c#, html, css, radio-button, blazor

I've got a list of radio buttons in each of the components I've created which read from and write to the database which is good, but when i select a radio button in one component it will unselect the radio button in the first / other components. How can I make it so I can select the radio buttons in all of the components.

radio buttons:

```
            <label class="GroupTitle">Filters:</label><br/>
            <input type="radio" name="number" id="all" checked="@checkedRadio("all", FileFilter)" @oninput="@(() => UpdateFilter("all"))" /> 
            <label for="">Clear all files</label><br />  
            <input type="radio" name="number" id="number" checked="@checkedRadio("number", FileFilter)" @oninput="@(() => UpdateFilter("number"))" />
            <label for="">Based on number of files</label><br />    
            <input type="radio" name="number" id="date"  checked="@checkedRadio("date", FileFilter)" @oninput="@(() => UpdateFilter("date"))" />    
            <label for="date">Based on date of files</label><br />
```

checkedRadio() :

```
    private bool checkedRadio(string state, FileFilter Filter)
    {
        if(state == Filter.Filter)
        {
            return true;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

UpdateFilter() :

```
    private void UpdateFilter(string option)
    {
        filter = option;
        FileFilter.Filter = option;
    }
```

Comment: It's likely they share the same name value.  That's how the browser knows which ones to unselect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

Comment: @Adam like the name="number" part?

Comment: Yes, correct. If you have four radio buttons and you give them all the same name (say "number") then when one is selected, the other three with the same name will unset. If you set two as "number1" and the other two as "number2" you'll see that checking the radio buttons will only turn off either of them. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Use check boxes. Style them as radio buttons if you must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your radio buttons are sharing the same name attribute.

```
name="number"
```

So it is behaving like a radio group should behave; radio buttons with the same name form a group of mutually exclusive values (this is HTML itself, not a Blazor thing.)  If your intended behavior is that multiple options can be selected, have a look at check boxes and give each a different name.

HTML Radio buttons:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio

HTML Checkboxes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox